Is there any way to config the number partion topic checkpoint of mirrormaker2
I use mirrormaker 2 to sync kafka A-> B. I want to increase performance consunmer group synchrony by increasing partition of topic checkpoint. Is there any way to config the number partion topic checkpoint of mirrormaker2
Is there any way to config the number partion topic checkpoint of mirrormaker2

clusterAlias.checkpoints.internal is a single-partition Compacted Topic
private void createInternalTopics() {
  MirrorUtils.createSinglePartitionCompactedTopic(
    config.checkpointsTopic(),
    config.checkpointsTopicReplicationFactor(),
    targetAdminClient
  );
}

If your goal is to improve synchronization speed, refresh.groups.interval.seconds Maybe this is the configuration item you want?
